# Speed up build by caching packages in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I have this idea that I haven't completed yet. In a Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

RUN "*cache node modules here*"
RUN e.g. npm cache add foo bar baz

COPY package.json .
RUN npm i --cache-min 9999999 --loglevel=warn

COPY . .

CMD node dist
```

How can I create ultra high-performance Dockerfiles by caching some Node.js modules/package before the npm install step?

Is there some trick that can do this?

Comment: would might happen is that your package.json file might change, but your dependencies wouldn't, or what not. I am also slightly confused - will the `npm i` command put modules in the cache that can be used if the `npm i` command runs again? My instinct says no, but my rational mind says "I don't know how Docker would/could prevent that".

Answer (score 6):

This is out-of-the-box Docker functionality.  If your Dockerfile says

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY ...
```

then, if the `package.json` hasn't changed, Docker will skip over the `RUN npm install` step and use the filesystem image that results from doing it.